# How to intersect the more than four arrays with empty array using PHP

Tags: php

I need to intersect more than fourarray with empty arrays .

```
I have four arrays:

array1 = array('10','20','36');
array2 = array();
array3 = array ('20');
array4 = array ('20','40');
```

How can I intersect the array ? . I need to get 20 as result ?

Comment: Intersection of anything with an empty array is an empty array (just like multiplication of any amount of numbers is zero when any one of them is a zero).

Comment: show how should look the expected result

Comment: I need to get 20 as result

Comment: you only have 4 ! miss one array ?

Comment: Not only array 2 was empty.  The fours and its values are change dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try `array_intersect`

your array2 was empty, then you wont get any common elements.

```
$array1 = array('10','20','36');
//$array2 = array();
$array3 = array ('20');
$array4 = array ('20','40');
//$a = array_intersect ( $array1 ,array2,  $array3, $array4 );
$a = array_intersect ( $array1 ,  $array3, $array4 );
print_r($a); //Array(    [1] => 20);
```